# have or has in a question like How many

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Which one is correct?
How many children does  Jack have?
               or
How many children does  Jack has?

If have is the correct answer, then rule of the grammar says if subject is a 3rd person then it will be has.So Jack is 3rd in the sentence.
 In either of the sentence which one is the subject , Jack or children.

Answer (score 1):

"Have" is correct. This is because of the "does" not because of the number of kids. So, all of the following are correct:

Jack has a child.
Jack does have a child.
Jack has 3 children.
Jack does have 3 children.
Has Jack got a child?
Does Jack have a child?

Comment: What is the meaning of this sentence ? which you have mentioned.Jack does have 3 children.

Comment: @asr09: We use "do-support" to frame *questions* (such as ***Does** he have three children?*), but it's not normally included in *statements*. We usually phrase the corresponding statement there as *He has three children,* but do-support can be used to provide emphasis and/or to refute what someone else just said. For example, *I don't think he has three children", "Well, I know for a fact that you are mistaken. He **does** have three children.*